# Framework UI WinForms c библиотеками готовых контролов

Tags: winforms, framework, ui

Посоветуйте достойный **Framework под WinForms C#** c готовыми стилями форм, компонентов, и контролов.

**Имеются**

1. **[DevExpress](https://www.devexpress.com/subscriptions/universal.xml)** лицензия Universal
2. **[MetroFramework](https://thielj.github.io/MetroFramework/)**
3. **[Materialskin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MaterialSkin.Updated/)**
4. **[Bunifu Framework](https://bunifuframework.com)**

поделитесь ссылками, примерами достойного фреймвока сегодня, не пишите о WPF и создании контролов, спасибо.

Comment: А каковы критерии «достойности»?

Comment: Проблема большинства фреймворков, отсутствие стилизации ListBox, TreeView и прочих сложных элементов..  Имелось в виду материалами и метро.

Answer (score 2):

Короче, не знаю, полезен будет ли кому-нибудь этот ответ, потому как один год назад был дан этот вопрос, но вот те UI Framework - и, которые юзаю я, и активно ищу новые.

**1. Guna.UI - https: //github.com/sobatdata/Guna.UI-Framework-Lib**
[image: Guna.UI]

**!!Однако учтите, что Guna2 платная, берите триал, а Guna1 бесплатная!!**

**2. Dark.UI - https: //github.com/RobinPerris/DarkUI**
[image: Dark.UI]

**!!DarkUI бесплатная, но для начала нужно её скомпилировать в Visual Studio!!**

**2. Xander UI, одна из самых красивых - http: //rickydivjakovski.com/products/ - тут пробел уберите**

[![Xander UI][3]][3]

**!!Вся эта красотища бесплатна!!**

**3. Nevron NOV Controls - https://www.nevron.com/**
[![Nevron][4]][4]

**Платная, берите триал. Привёл её просто потому что она есть.**

**4.VisualPlus, также одна из лучших - https:// github.com/DarkByte7/VisualPlus/wiki/WinForms-UI-Controls - тут пробел уберите**
Пикчи на сайте

**5 и 6. Skeet и Reich UI - https:// github.com/aabsolute/skeet-ui-framework - тут пробел уберите, https:// github.com/giladreich/ReichUI-WinForms - тут пробел...**
Skeet[![Skeet][5]][5]

У Reich -a картинку дать не могу, т.к устал и не хочу заморачиваться.

***АРХИВ СО ВСЕМИ МОИМИ UI***
***https://yadi.sk/d/jdB46vm___Lagg***
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2igaj.png
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEbro.png
[5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kK1N.png